# How to use Bootstrap 4 display for various screens

Tags: bootstrap-4, show-hide

I am a newbie and NOT a coder. This is my first post.

I have a website design where I want the main design to show on devices md, lg, xl. what code to I use for this section?

then when it gets smaller than 576, I want the main design to be hidden and another design to be revealed--this design works better on small devices. What code do I use for this section?

If I use the "d" codes, do I still have to do media queries in CSS?????

I can't make sense of the B4 documentation.Thank you.

Comment: Watch a tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to check out a few YouTube tutorials on not only Bootstrap, but general HTML5 and CSS tutorials. As you are new to the *coding* world, you need to hone in on the basics before jumping into an HTML/CSS framework, such as Bootstrap.